# Determining both kinds of situations with Regex

Tags: regex

The following regex code; after the number, it detects the period, but not if there is a space between the number and the text.

```
(\d+|d+\s)\.\s*([0-9a-zA-Z].*?)\s+([0-9a-zA-Z]\..*?)(?=\d+\.\s*[0-9a-zA-Z]|$)
```

> 51. Test this is first string and random digits:15*893 A.TEST B. TEST2 52.Test this is second string A.TEST B. TEST2 53 . This is 3th string A.TEST B. TEST2 54. this is next string.. A.TEST B. TEST2

Part 53 does not detect. What is the reason of this?

https://regex101.com/r/MqBcB6/2

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Unfortunately, when there is a gap between some numbers and points, the layout is broken. - The expected output should look like this: https://pastebin.com/xQ9RLrfZ @Nick

Comment: How can you get that output when the 3rd and 4th strings don't have both `A. ` and `B .` sections?

Comment: I actually have, but I've added such to ask quick questions. @Nick

Comment: Can I ask question @Nick Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? I just wondered

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly you're trying to do here. You want to match all text that comes after numbers followed by dots, but the match should terminate when it encounters `A.` or `B.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to allow for spaces between the digits and `.` where you check for them (at the start of the regex and in the lookahead):

```
(\d+)\s*\.\s*([0-9a-zA-Z].*?)\s+([0-9a-zA-Z]\..*?)(?=\d+\s*\.\s*[0-9a-zA-Z]|$)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MqBcB6/3)

Comment: What if there were braces instead of dots? For example; `53)` or `53 )` -- Is it possible to do if else? for dot or braces.

Comment: @Emre5 just replace `\.` at the beginning and in the lookahead with `\)`

Comment: I mean; maybe there may not be a dot mark, how should there be a parentheses instead of a dot mark? Like `if else` @Nick

Comment: If you mean there could be a `.` **or** a `)`, then replace the `\.` at the beginning and in the lookahead with `[.)]` https://regex101.com/r/MqBcB6/4